# pass isDevMode to forRoot throw error in Prod env

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

the code like as bellow

```
const isDev = isDevMode()
const modules = [
    HttpClientModule,
    NgxsModule.forRoot(AllStates, { developmentMode: isDev }),
]
```

this code work well in development env, but will throw an error in prod env.
The error is `Error during template compile of 'CoreModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'isDevMode' was called.`

Is there a way to pass isDevMode to forRoot function?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I use `const isDev = !environment.production` , and work well.